# Android 4.4, undefined reference to __printf_chk

Tags: c, android-make, fortify-source

I am moving some libraries from Android 4.3 to Android 4.4

The projects that used to compile in Android 4.3 now gives below error when compiled using Android 4.4 sources

/home/vishallocal/TI/android/kitkat/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/i686-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/sysroot/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:105: error: undefined reference to '__printf_chk'
/home/vishallocal/TI/android/kitkat/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/i686-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/sysroot/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:105: error: undefined reference to '__printf_chk'
/home/vishallocal/TI/android/kitkat/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/i686-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/sysroot/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:105: error: undefined reference to '__printf_chk'
/home/vishallocal/TI/android/kitkat/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/i686-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/sysroot/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:105: error: undefined reference to '__printf_chk'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Any pointers on resolving this?

Comment: Use recursive grep to figure out where this is/was used and defined.  Did you move object files between versions rather than moving cleaned source?  Are you using non-public internal functionality in your code?

Comment: I moved just the source... googling around, looks like FORTIFY_CHECK is causing printf to call this

Comment: Figured out a solution: compiling the project by disabling FORTIFY_SOURCE fixes the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the issue by building the project with FORTIFY_SOURCE flag disabled

Added following lines to Android.mk
`LOCAL_CFLAGS += -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE`

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer can be improved:

> ```
> Fixed the issue by building the project with FORTIFY_SOURCE flag disabled
>
> Added following lines to Android.mk LOCAL_CFLAGS += -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE
> ```

You probably want something like:

```
ifeq ($(APP_OPTIM),debug)
  LOCAL_CFLAGS += -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE
endif
```

Also, you might get a warning if using `FORTIFY_SOURCE` and `-O0`. Its safe to ignore the warning. You can dispatch the waring with `-O1` or similar.

`FORTIFY_SOURCE` is available to applications in NDK R10 and above. Prior to that, `FORTIFY_SOURCE` was only used with system libraries. I'm not sure how to guard on "NDK R10" and above. See [Fortify Sources and Stack Protectors (was: Is Fortify Source working with NDK)](http://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-security-discuss/4iCOgYnCVQk/KOOtOUkKCOcJ) on the Android Security Discussions mailing list.

Also, if you disable `FORTIFY_SOURCE` in release builds, then it should trigger a security defect.